# Why does accessing TextView from within onTimeSet() function produces a runtime error?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, datetimepicker, timepickerdialog

I've just started learning Android development using Kotlin and ran into this error.

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers) guide to create some basic time and date picker dialogues which are triggered through their respective button presses. Here is a code snippet of the TimePickerFragment class for the reference:

```
class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)


    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return TimePickerDialog(activity, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(activity))
}

override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
    //
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    timeSet = true
    //val timeText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeView)
    //timeView.text = getString(R.string.time_str, hourOfDay, minute)
    timeStr = "$hourOfDay : $minute"
    //timeView.setText(timeStr)

}
```

So, as you might have noticed in the code above, I've been struggling with the onTimeSet() function.
What I wish to do is to update a TextView's current text with the time user just selected. However, at runtime when I press OK, the app crashes.

Is it illegal to do that in Kotlin? How else can this be done?

**edit:**

logcat crash report:

```
2020-12-13 05:24:28.831 5480-5480/com.example.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myproject, PID: 5480
java.lang.IllegalStateException: timeView must not be null
    at com.example.myproject.TimePickerFragment.onTimeSet(MainActivity2.kt:81)
    at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:172)
    at android.app.TimePickerDialog$1.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:154)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:782)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25945)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: please post the logcat crash report

Comment: "What I wish to do is to update a TextView's current text with the time user just selected" -- this fragment does not have that `TextView`. Something else does. You need to get your data to whatever has that `TextView`.

Comment: @Zain Sorry but how do I do that?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yup, the 'TextView' is in the activity by which this fragment is being created.

Comment: When you run on a device conncted to Android studio.. There's a Logcat tab at the bottom toolbar contains several types of logs including errors

Comment: @Chucky You should get your data from the `MainActivity` itself or you need a `TextView` in the `Fragment` to get the desired output

Comment: @Zain did that, edited the post

Comment: @Chucky Did you call `findViewById()` from `Fragment`?

Comment: @Vishnu So should I return the values of `hourOfDay` and `minute` to the main activity? How to do that?

Comment: @Vishnu yes I did call `findViewById()` from fragment. That didn't work, so I imported `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main2.*` but this didn't work either

Comment: @Chucky You can do everything from `MainActivity`. Am I right? Also, you had better not access views of `MainActivity` from `Fragment`

Comment: I mean, showing `Dialog` & `Overriding` methods from `MainActivity` itself... As in the documentation you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Following the question + comments, it seems that you're trying to access a `TextView` that belongs to your `Activity` inside the `TimePickerFragment` and that's just not going to work. Instead, you need to pass back the significant data to your `Activity`, and only then attempt to change your `TextView`.

A very easy way of doing this, for example, is to have in your `Activity` a public method

```kt
fun setTime(timeStr: String) {
    timeView.text = timeStr
}
```

which your `TimePickerFragment` could access directly by calling

```kt
(requireActivity() as YourActivity).setTime(...)
```

as soon as `onTimerSet(..)` is called through the listener.

Of course, there are many other ways of communicating with your `Activity` like sending back a result so you'll have to see what works better with your system.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around, the `TimePickerFragment` is inside the `Activity`. But I do get what you are saying. Only if you could elaborate on " `(requireActivity() as YourActivity).setTime(...)` " it would be really helpful.

Comment: That's what Ivan's saying, you're trying to access a ``TextView`` that belongs to your ``Activity`` from inside the ``TimePickerFragment`` instead. The suggestion here is to give the parent activity a ``setTime`` method, then get the activity and call that method from inside the dialog. The method is inside the activity, so it can see the ``TextView`` inside the activity's layout

Comment: @cactustictacs doing so made the app throw a `NullPointerException`  T_T